# Парсинг сайта на питоне

Tags: python

Что и как лучше сделать для моей задачи. Например просто для парсера страницы использую requests и BeautifulSoup, это понятно. Но мне нужно с помощью программы на питоне, при запуске ввести текст и этот текст должен вставляться в поиск, а после уже парсинг.(ну имею ввиду что-то похожее, то что можно сделать руками на сайте, сделать программой)
Например, запустил программу, ввел текст "процессоры" и далее я уже работал бы со страницей с процессорами, ну то есть парсил страницу с процессорами

Comment: 1. [selenium](https://habr.com/ru/post/248559/); 2. Можно сформировать запрос, уже включающий строку для поиска, например: [https://www.google.com/search?q=Hello+world!](https://www.google.com/search?q=Hello+world!)

Comment: хорошо буду пробовать

Comment: да, я понимаю что так можно сделать, но не везде такая функция есть, например если я напишу "avito процессор", то может я и получу ссылку и ее распарсить смогу. но как и сказал не везде такое есть. мне бы как-то узнать способ чтобы вводить именно на сайте что-нибудь в тег input, сайт на html. Моя ошибка, забыл указать что не просто в поиске должен ввести что-то, а после распарсить, а нужно на определенном сайте

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто отправить искать по `google`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
search = input('mmm.. :')
search = search.replace(' ', '+') # Заменяем пробелы на плюсы
g_poisk = requests.get('https://google.com/search?q='+search).text # Делаем запрос

htmlka = BS(g_poisk)
# Парсим....
```